# Refactoring/renaming within comments in Visual C# Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, comments, rename

When refactor->renaming MyMethod in the following example in Visual C# 2010 Express, the method name 'MyMethod' in the comment won't be changed.

Usually that a comment isn't touched by refactor/rename is for good reasons, since how should the IDE know that it's not just some word but actually references the very method that it is refactoring.

So is there a way in which a word in a comment can be bound to a class/method/variable name within Visual C# 2010 Express, so that it's changed as well during refactoring/renaming?

If there are several ways what would be the easiest/cheapest way?
(cheapest - in case of plugins or commercial versions)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  /// text for class MyClass
  public class MyClass
  {
    /// <summary><c>MyMethod</c> is a method in the <c>MyClass</c> class.
    /// </summary>
    public static void MyMethod(int Int1)
    {
    }
    /// text for Main
    public static void Main()
    {
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Resharper will check the XML Comments. However, in your example, those comments add to clutter and have no value. Its obvious that MyMethod(int) is a method in Main() As you've encountered, they add friction by causing you to maintain stuff that is not code.

Comment: There's nothing in Visual Studio 2010 that will do that out of the box. I don't know of any existing plugins that will do it, either. It'd be possible to do, but certainly not trivial.

Comment: @Jim Mischel - Resharper does this sort of thing incredibly well.

Comment: @Ritch Melton: I guess I'll have to give Resharper a look.

Comment: @Ritch Melton: Very obviously the comments don't add anything since the whole program doesn't do anything at all. It's just a tiny example for refactoring not a question about good comments. It's just meant as a small time-saver when someone thinks he has a possible solution he can just copy&paste it and try it without the need to write a few lines himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in the commercial editions, the rename dialog (press <kbd>F2</kbd>) has an `Search in Comments` checkbox.

Comment: +1 thx the express version has that as well and I actually overlooked that. While this doesn't bind it to a variable/method/class-name as asked it should do the trick, since the comments are shown separated from the code in the Preview dialog and each replacement can be (de-)selected separately.

Comment: I guess it was the same "revenge-downvoter" that did it with my question. There was one answer that had wrong info and well seemed to have not really understood the question so I downvoted it and explained in a comment why. Coming back now I see his answer was deleted, the question downvoted and the accepted answer downvoted as well. Of course all those three things without leaving a comment. But hey it's just a very wild guess that it was this person ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure about the Express edition, but VS 2008 professional edition we can do it:

- http://www.thereforesystems.com/refactoring-in-visual-studio-2008/

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.23_Express), the Renaming refactoring mentioned in other answers should be available in the Express edition. So try Ctrl-R-R, F2 or right-click/Refactor/Rename.